# How do I return CGpoint function?

Tags: objective-c

If i have this function:

```
 -(CGPoint)limitPosition:(CGPoint)position {
          //code here

              return position;
      }
```

how do I return it to a variable?

This:

```
CGPoint a;
CGPoint b;

a = [self limitPosition: b];
```

Doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Without a clearer description of what you mean by "doesn't work", and probably what's going on where you have `//code here`, it's hard to say.

Basically, you *can* pass a `CGPoint` to and from a function or method with the syntax as you have it. It'll be passed *by value*, so that any changes to `position` inside the function will not be reflected in the variable passed as argument (`b`), but should be copied back in the return value (to `a`).

In the code fragment shown, you don't initialise `a` or `b`, so they may contain garbage. And obviously the method body isn't doing much. But otherwise it looks kosher, so the problem is probably elsewhere.